# Unity - play services : Cant register Classes

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, service, google-play

Im using unity 2017.1.0f3 with the appodeal plugin for ad mediation and i tried to implement google play services 0.9.4.1. But somehow i always encounter this problem here.

```
GamesUnitySDK: Performing Android initialization of the GPG SDK
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Games: an exception occurred.
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Games$GamesOptions: an exception occurred.
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Games$GamesOptions$Builder: an exception occurred.
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Player: an exception occurred.
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/PlayerBuffer: an exception occurred.
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/PlayerLevel: an exception occurred.
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/PlayerLevelInfo: an exception occurred.
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Players: an exception occurred.
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Players$LoadPlayersResult: an exception occurred.
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievement: an exception occurred.
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements$LoadAchievementsResult: an exception occurred.
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/event/Event: an exception occurred.
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/event/EventBuffer: an exception occurred.
GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/event/Events: an exception occurred.
AudioFlinger::EffectModule: EffectModule 0xae103d80 destructor called with unreleased interface
AudioFlinger::EffectHandle: disconnect Effect handle 0xae8ff400 disconnected after thread destruction
Unity   : Building GPG services, implicitly attempts silent auth
Unity   :
Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
Unity   :
GamesNativeSDK: Could not register one or more required Java classes.
Unity   : InvalidOperationException: There was an error creating a GameServices object. Check for log errors from GamesNativeSDK
Unity   :   at GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.GameServicesBuilder.Build (GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.PlatformConfiguration configRef) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
Unity   :   at GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient.InitializeGameServices () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
Unity   :   at GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient.Authenticate (System.Action`2 callback, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
Unity   :   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Authenticate (System.Action`2 callback, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
Unity   :   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
Unity   :   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
Unity   :   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesLocalUser.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
Unity   :   at PlayServiceMan
Unity   : Programm Starts
```

I shortened it a bit. In the original file there where about 50 more cant register class logs.

I tried to reinstall the plugin several times. Updated all my sdks to the newest version and checked the .aar files ( all are the same version ) . What the hell im doing wrong ? I also used the Google Play Service Setup multiple times that didnt helped either...

I heard some people talking about a plugins/android/googleplayservice_lib folder, but theres no im my project. All the .aar files are in the /plugins/android dictionary.

I really hope that someone can help me.... how hard can it be to install play services?